# Tcpdf is not able to write thousands of records

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf library in my one of the project and the issue i am facing is while trying to add more than 1000 records using with table structure using writeHtml or Writhtmlcell function of tcpdf, it is not going to outcome as pdf. it crashed all the time and shows white page instead.

Tried lots of way but didn't work any.

Please suggest any solution if it is there.

Any help will truly be appreciated.

Regards,
Jenish

Comment: you run out of memory, that's the reason. you should fetch your data in batches, not 1000 at once and also make sure your script can use a considerable amount of memory since pdf generation will eat memory. See `memory_limit` directive from your `php.ini` file for this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already added memory_limit as '-1' in my current file where i am using this library and also tried with chunk of data. actually full data is 11000 and i have divided them in the chunk of only 50 then also it is not working.

Comment: you are trying to generate a single pdf with more than 1000 lines of database data am i right

Comment: maybe your script times out, have you taken this into consideration? how about running this script from command line, same behavior ?

Comment: Yes that may be script timeout but this should not happen i think. This is 11000 records and this should be generated within 8 minutes. My php.ini contains 8 minutes for max_execution_time variable.

Answer (score 2):

Solve the problem by installing **XCACHE**, It really speeds up the operation.

or,

You can also use MPDF, give it a try.

Comment: Actually i am done with my application with tcpdf and i found this issue after on. So, i am not able to move down on MPDF. So, let me try XCACHE. Does it affect any other functionality ? or it is only for Tcpdf ?